# Why isn't my razor helper being executed inside a Using statement?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This view:

```
@Using Html.BeginForm
    SimpleMessage
End Using

@Helper SimpleMessage()
    @<p>This is a simple message</p>
End Helper
```

Results in

```
<form action="/Controller/Action" method="post"></form>
```

But

```
@* Now let's not call it from within a using *@
@SimpleMessage

@Helper SimpleMessage()
    @<p>This is a simple message</p>
End Helper
```

Results in

```
<p>This is a simple message</p>
```

Why doesn't my helper work while inside my `Using Html.BeginForm`?

Comment: This is a pure guess since I only know a tiny bit about Razor, but what happens if you use the `@` symbol in front of `SimpleMessage` inside the using?

Comment: You got it! How did I miss that? I figured that since I'm inside code I don't need `@` to call a function, which is true, but apparently you do for razor helpers.

Comment: @jpmc26, I think you're half right. I think he also needs the **()**

Comment: Don't need parentheses in VB.NET, although I might add them for consistency :)

Comment: Ahaaa... Yeah I've spent the last 3 years exclusively in c#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `@` symbol in front of the helper method.

```
@Using Html.BeginForm
    @SimpleMessage
End Using
```